# get IP address from inside a virtual machine

Tags: python, windows, perl, unix, virtual-machine

I am running a UNIX operating system via xming , and I am trying to figure out a way to write a script that will run from the Linux terminal and print the ip of the windows computer that is running the xming session.

I don't even know if this is possible , but if it is I'll be glad for some help.

By the way, the computer is in a private network and I am not allowed to install new software.

p.s. : if there is a perl/python function that can help me it will be good enough.

Comment: This would depend a lot on what virtualization software you use and how it's configured, none of which you mention. Also, a lot of the point of a VM is isolation from the outer environment, which means some things are simply not known to the virtualized OS and are difficult or impossible for it to determine.

Comment: A simple but possibly incorrect way would be to use any of the "what-is-my-ip" services. Just fetch the page and parse it (or use an API if available). However, if the server is behind a NAT firewall/router you will get its IP-address and not the server's.

Comment: @gurka I forgot to mention : the computers are part of a private network...

Comment: @DanLowe Saying that the software is xming is good enough or should I give more info?

Comment: xming is an X11 window server system, that's not a virtualization engine. A VM would be inside something like vmware or virtualbox...

Comment: @DanLowe sorry for the ignorance  , I thought that xming was a VM. I know that I can google it , but can you explain why xming is not a VM (I am not familiar with the notion of X11 windows server system and the difference between it and a vm)

Answer (score 0):

**If your VM is using 'NAT' network settings:** (which is also the default setting)
 
You can find the IP of host machine by simply tracing the route of a website. For example, run the command:

```
traceroute http://www.anywebsite.com/
```

This will show you all the intermediate systems' IP between website and your VM, including the IP of your VM's host machine, as your traffic is passing through it.

**How to install?** `sudo apt-get install traceroute` (on ubuntu/debian based)

Some similar tools on UNIX/Linux are: `traceroute, traceroute6, tracepath`

**If you are using 'Bridged Adapater' network settings**:
You can use tools like, [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/download/) and scan all IPs on your network. If not disabled by host, you will be able to get details of all systems, atleast basic and you can try determine your host. If only one system is there in the network, then, Bingo! You don't need to do much :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving from the comments into an answer...

You have been asking about a VM running on your Windows PC, but it is not clear that you are even doing so. You seem to be using [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/), which is an X11 server for Windows. That is not the same thing as a VM.

Now, it is still possible you are using a VM. If you are, it would be running in a virtualization program, such as VMware, Oracle Virtualbox, or some other virtual machine software. It is difficult for us to know from this vantage point. If you are in a corporate environment, you can get a clear answer by asking your IT department.

It seems more likely that you are using Xming to connect to another system which is running an X11 server. X11 allows you to display graphical UI from a remote computer onto your own computer. It is normally something you use with a Unix/Linux server. Probably this X11 server is on some other machine on your network, and not a VM on your PC.

In which case the best advice I can offer is to look at the `$DISPLAY` variable on the Unix/Linux server, if you have a shell window open to it.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
DISPLAY=10.1.2.3:12345
```

That may show you the IP of your PC (probably followed by a port number), which X11 is connecting to for display. If you can't see that though, I'm not sure what else you can try.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
But actually I am trying to write a script in order to set $DISPLAY to the computer's IP address , because each time I connect to Xming he gives me a bad display address.

Comment: @UserB95 How do you connect to the server? SSH? If so, SSH is supposed to take care of that stuff for you, as long as you have the client configured properly. Otherwise, running "who" on the server will hopefully tell you what IP address you are coming from.